# Multiple Spring's SecurityConfigs not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to configure two SecurityConfigs simultaneously. The `SecurityConfig` requires an Oauth authorization at Keycloak Auth Server (embedded in a separate Spring app). The `OauthSecurityConfig` requires an Oauth authorization at GoogleApi. Both configs DO work, when implemented separately (when I define just one config at a time).

Right now, only one of them works (the one annotated with `@Order(1)`). I'm trying to implementing them both in the following way:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiSecurityConfig {
    
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/auth/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("SCOPE_read", "SCOPE_write")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt();
        }

        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
            return source;
        }

    }
    
    @Configuration
    public static class OauthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/**")
                    .authenticated()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for multiple SecurityConfigs to work you have to define '.antMatcher()` at each config, like so:

```
http.antMatcher("/auth/**").cors()
    .and()
    ...
```